# Run Python OpenCV Haar classifier on website

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, web

I have created custom haar cascade classifiers that I want to integrate on my webpage.

The classifiers recognize hand gestures. On my webpage, I simply need a div that has camera feed and various gestures. Also I need to generate action when gesture is detected. The website is hosted using Heroku.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't run python directly on the client side, you will need to use Django as a Backend Server, send the camera feed to the backend to process it and send an answer back to the webpage.

Comment: Have a look at OpenCV JS: [tutorial face detection in JS](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d6c/tutorial_js_face_detection_camera.html).